# List of time orders

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making time orders. During certain hours (10:00 - 11:00, 11:30 - 12:30, 13:00 - 14: 000) only a certain number of items should be ordered. If the maximum number is reached, the ordering option should be deactivated. I list items via ajax so that they load according to availability when the time changes.
I've tried many ways, but I can't.

http://rezervace.pcserviskv.cz/step1/

Output:

**2020-05-18**

10:00 - 11:00 - Item 1  (2/0)

10:00 - 11:00 - Item 2  (4/0)

**2020-05-18**

11:30 - 12:30 - Item 1  (2/1)

11:30 - 12:30 - Item 2  (2/0)

**2020-05-18**

13:00 - 14:00 - Item 1  (2/0)

13:00 - 14:00 - Item 2  (4/1)

**2020-05-19**

10:00 - 11:00 - Item 1  (2/0)

10:00 - 11:00 - Item 2  (4/0)

**2020-05-19**

11:30 - 12:30 - Item 1  (2/2) - out of stock

11:30 - 12:30 - Item 2  (2/0)

**2020-05-19**

13:00 - 14:00 - Item 1  (2/0)

13:00 - 14:00 - Item 2  (4/4) - out of stock

```
    -- Product

create table product
(
    id    int auto_increment
        primary key,
    name  varchar(255) not null,
    count int(3)       not null,
    input varchar(255) not null,
    price int(5)       not null
);

INSERT INTO product (id, name, quantity, input, price) VALUES 
(3, 'Item 1', 2, 'item1', 500), 
(4, 'Item 2', 4, 'item2', 1000);


    -- orders

create table orders
(
    id         int auto_increment
        primary key,
    number     int          not null,
    product    varchar(255) not null,
    date       date         not null,
    time_start time         not null,
    time_end   time         not null
);

INSERT INTO orders (id, number, date, time_start, time_end, first_name, last_name, email, phone) VALUES 
(1, 0, '2020-05-18', '11:30:00', '12:30:00', '', '', '', ''),
(2, 0, '2020-05-18', '13:00:00', '14:00:00', '', '', '', ''),
(3, 0, '2020-05-19', '11:30:00', '12:30:00', '', '', '', ''),
(4, 0, '2020-05-19', '13:00:00', '14:00:00', '', '', '', '');


    -- order_items

create table order_items
(
    id           int(4) auto_increment
        primary key,
    order_id     int(4)       not null,
    product_name varchar(255) not null,
    quantity     int(2)       not null
);

INSERT INTO order_items (id, order_id, product_id, product_name, quantity) VALUES 
(1, 1, 3, 'Item 1', 1),
(2, 2, 4, 'Item 2', 1),
(3, 3, 3, 'Item 1', 2),
(4, 4, 4, 'Item 2', 4);
```

```
SELECT i.id as id, i.product_id as product_id, SUM(ifnull(i.quantity, 0)) as quantity_order, p.name
as name, p.price as price, p.quantity as quantity,
p.input as input, o.time_start as time_start, o.time_end as time_end
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN order_items i ON p.id = i.product_id
LEFT JOIN orders o on o.id = i.order_id
WHERE (o.date = '2020-05-18') AND (o.time_start = '11:30:00') AND (o.time_end = '12:30:00') or
i.product_id IS NULL or i.id 
GROUP BY p.id, o.time_start, o.time_end
```

```php
foreach ($products as $product) {
  if($product->quantity <= $product->quantity_order && $product->time_start == $time->time_start) {
  echo $product->name . "out of stock";
 } else {
      echo $product->name . "<input type="number">";
        }
}
```

Comment: Pls follow this guidance to improve your question because I have absolutely no idea what your compkex query is supposed to do and what it is actually doing! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Replace tables with according CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: Show desired output for shown data. If some external conditions needed - specify them.