# LEFT JOIN every time with null

Tags: php, mysql

I would need advice on how to join tables so that product names and numbers are always displayed, even if the other tables have zero values.
It has to do with this [List of time orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61866146/list-of-time-orders)

Maybe I'm going the wrong way and I should look for a solution in PHP.

I need to see the number of items each day and at certain hours in order to view the status available or unavailable.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a343a3/6

Comment: *how to join tables so that product names and numbers are always displayed* - If so than the table which stores this data must be left in the join.

Comment: put your `WHERE` criteria into the `ON` join criteria.

Comment: But your error is in WHERE clause. The conditions by right table(s) must be in ON clause, not in WHERE clause. Now they converts your LEFT join to INNER (because they ejects added pseudo-rows with NULLs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    p.`name`, 
    p.quantity, 
    p.input, 
    p.price,
    ifnull(oo.quantity,0) as count
FROM
    product AS p
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT
        i.product_id,
        sum(i.quantity) as quantity
    FROM
        order_items AS i
        INNER JOIN
        orders AS o
        ON 
            i.order_id = o.id
        WHERE (`o`.`date` = '2020-05-20') AND (`o`.`time_start` = '11:30:00') AND (`o`.`time_end` = '12:30:00')
        GROUP BY i.product_id) AS oo
    ON 
        p.id = oo.product_id
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Put the `where` conditions in the `join`

```
SELECT p.name, p.quantity, p.input as input, p.price as price, SUM(ifnull(i.quantity,0)) as count
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN order_items i ON p.id = i.product_id
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.id = i.order_id
                  AND `o`.`date` = '2020-05-20'
                  AND `o`.`time_start` = '11:30:00'
                  AND `o`.`time_end` = '12:30:00'
GROUP BY p.name
```

Otherwise your `where` clause would turn your `left join` into an `inner join`

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a343a3/8)

Comment: Thank you. I tried it according to this example, but when I change the date, it completely ignores it and shows the column "count" still "2".
Orders are now only on 2020-05-20

Comment: Could you show your problem in another SQLFiddle? I don't quite get it

Comment: In DB exist only two orders in date 2020-05-20. If change date to 2020-05-20, so the number should be Item1 = 0, Item2 = 0.
Solution from @sachinkumaraliyanage works